# Repeated subreports don't show parameters

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've imported 3 different subreports into my main report multiple times. I pass their parameters like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rlc.ReportLayout.Count; i++)
{
    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest1.rpt")
    {
        SetSectionOneReportParameters(reportParameterList);
    }
    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest2.rpt")
    {
        SetSectionTwoReportParameters(reportParameterList);
    }
    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest3.rpt")
    {
        SetSectionThreeReportParameters(reportParameterList);
    }
}
```

Somehow only the first report seems to get the parameters:

[image]

Every color represent a subreport. What I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
private void SetSectionOneReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
{
    reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterOne", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest1.rpt" });
}

private void SetSectionTwoReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
{
    reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterTwo", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest2.rpt" });
}

private void SetSectionThreeReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
{
    reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterThree", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest3.rpt" });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare all your parameters with "Shared" in your main report, then you can access them in all your subreport.

Try declaring `Shared numbervar myparam` in the main report, and reuse the same syntax in the subreport where you want to use it, no C# required. (If you still want to use C#, use the SetParameterValue method from crystal report.)

Here is an example from ["1.4.3.1.4 To set discrete parameters in a report"](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet13_sp14_dg_en.pdf):

```
private void SettingParameters_RD(ReportDocument TestReport)
{
    string PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME = "Country";
    ArrayList countries = new ArrayList();
    countries.Add("Canada");
    countries.Add("USA");
    TestReport.SetParameterValue(PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME, countries.ToArray());
    crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = TestReport;
}
```

Simply use this in your code by accessing your subreports:

```
mainreport.Subreports["subreportname"].SetParameterValue("paramname","values");
```

Your code didn't edit the subreport's object and parameters collection. This  should correct that